# Where to add google recaptcha secret and response code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am trying to deploy https://github.com/jus/huuu.github.io
to heroku. Site is live at https://floating-retreat-20794.herokuapp.com , I get "ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key" for recaptcha. I register a new recaptcha. Where I can put my key, secret and response in this code. I am a newbie. Thanks.
Edit: I added only recaptcha key to code (secret key and response not added) But it seems to be working...Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file inside `config/initializers/` like `recaptcha.rb`

On the `recaptcha.rb` look like this

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
    config.site_key = '6LfKFQoUxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    config.secret_key = '6LfKFQoUAxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
end
```

And then restart the server

Comment: Without these code I think it is working now. Can you please test it at my site https://floating-retreat-20794.herokuapp.com/